# Follow Follow Follow Follow

Tags: bug, advertising

I just got this ad while using the Brave browser:

[image: ad with 4 Follow buttons]

The buttons work:

[image: 2 Following and 2 Follow buttons]

Otherwise, nothing else happens (the ad doesn't open another page). It's not scrollable either.

What is this an ad for? Is this a bug?

Comment: It appears at least some of the content is being blocked by a content filter or ad blocker.

Comment: I think it wants you to follow it.

Comment: Perhaps it's a yellow brick road advert.

Comment: [Vogons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaiX680XWP4&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFUOPyA8aLONTz5jr-IQFu5&index=4&t=11m20s)?

Comment: Reminds me of [They Live (1998)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjw_DuNkOUw)

Comment: "♪ Try to remember ♫ Eternal September ♬ then follow ... follow ... follow ... follow ..."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably got an ad similar to this one, with an ad blocker active:

[image]

The ad html uses adclick.g.doubleclick.net for most parts, allowing an ad blocker to block them, but not for the follow button.

Comment: I don't use an ad blocker, but Brave Shield was partially active - that might've caused it to appear like that on my end.